# How to set up 3 level workflow in GIT?

Tags: git, git-workflow

Currently i have a workflow of 2 levels (local<->online), but i would like to have a 3 level workflow by getting  a demo server in the middle (local<->demo<->online). 
I will describe in details how it is set up currently, and what in details i would like to achieve eventually.

**What i have now** -

- multiple local repositories of the same project (my PC and colluegues
  PCs)
- online site server (where the site is available to public use,    me
  or other devs from the team may push their ready parts of work from their localhost repositories to here, and pull from here, this is a bare repository added to the local ones over origin master, once pushed up online a hook automatically deploys the pushed changes).

**What i would like to have** -

- multiple local repositories of the same project (my PC and colluegues
  PCs)
- demo server where all devs can push and pull from to their local repositories. There should be automatic deployment. Once tested on demo the project should go up online. ( i am in doubt how to incorporate all this part...)
- online bare repository where, we push and pull from the demo server repository. If pushed from demo, it should be auto deployed.

**What is the best way to organize this kind of workflow?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's really the hard part for you as you seem to have all the needed bits ready…

You already have the toughest bit working: auto-deployment from your online repo. So, just make the same setup for your demo repo as you have in your online repo, and then the only missing step will be sending the state in the demo repo to online.

But since any Git repo is just a Git repo, you can push or fetch from it, so there's no difference whether you're pushing from developer boxes to online repo or you're pushing from demo repo to online repo.  If you're confused by the fact the demo repo is supposed to be bare, then fear not — you can both push and fetch from a bare repo as well; the only commands which do not work in bare repos are those which touch the index and the work tree.

What you should supposedly concentrate on is how you're supposed to work with the demo repo in a broader sense.  Say, are you OK with making quick fixes in the demo repo?  If so, they have to be fetched by the developers, or they have to be pushed to the online repo first and then fetched from there…

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 2 good points that you mention and i will keep in mind - 1) bare to bare repository is fine. 2) thinking of a bigger picture for the workflow. And i guess, the more levels you add, the stricter you need to stick to definite rules in the workflow, not to mess up something.

Comment: Also, I will try to stick to working locally, applying the changes to demo and when all is finished, and tested, applying online. I would like to remove the local and the demo files and repos, and keep only online bare repo for reference of all changes applied. I think, that's fine too. (i would upvote your answer, but i am not allowed to yet..)

Comment: i am stuck at a point when the demo server needs a (separate?) git user to create an SSH key pair to further push and pull to online server then. I was not able to find yet how to set up the user and keys on a remote server for it to act further as a git user. Any suggestions here?